# Date returning nil in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function like given below, and the date is displaying nil as in the screenshot, But while printing it shows the value. Did I miss something?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-07-27 04:01:46")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is perfect valid in playground, is this the string to erase to date or are you parsing a request and convert to date

Comment: The `date` variable is an optional `Date`.   Code above works fine. Are you unwrapping it?

Comment: The string comes from api response in the format "2020-07-27 04:01:46",

Comment: I'd double check the input then and make sure it's not being escaped, etc.  Maybe add a breakpoint on that last line and inspect the variables to validate your assumptions